# Return first cell in range between target values

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I want to get the value of the first cell in a range that is between two values.
The best I can do is get the first cell that is either smaller or larger than a value. I want the first cell that is BOTH larger than a value AND smaller than an other value.
This did not work (because it's only 1 criteria):

```
{=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(TRUE,A1:A10<B1,0))}
```

note: A1:A10 is the rage of values and B1 is the comparison

I tried:

```
{=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(TRUE,and(A1:A10<B1,A1:A10>B2),0))}
```

but it did not work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you use a helper column?

Comment: Yes I could if needed.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I wrote it without access to excel, but when I try it, I get a #N/A error, so I guess it doesn't

Comment: @chrisneilsen you are right! I just had the min and max number confused in my example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(1,(A1:A10<B1)*(A1:A10>B2),0))}
```

Please note, that it is an array formula, therefore you don't have to write the `{}`, but when you enter the formula, do this with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you everywhere in sheet.

```
=INDEX(A1:A10,SMALL(IF(A1:A10>=B1,IF(A1:A10<=B2,ROW(A1:A10)-ROW(A1)+1)),ROWS(A1:A1)))
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) instead of [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to return the relative row position to [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$10)/(($A$2:$A$11<$B$1)*($A$2:$A$11>$B$2)), ROW(1:1)))
```

This forces non-matching row numbers to a `#DIV/0!` error. The **6** option tells AGGREGATE to ignore errors.

Since this uses AGGREGATE's [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29), incresing the *k* parameter will produce the second, third, etc. matches as you fill `ROW(1:1)` down.

[image: agg_less_than]

Note that I've shifted your sample range down a row. This was done to illustrate that `ROW(1:10)` is the *position within* A2:A11, not the actual row number on the worksheet.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>